# How to enlarge a cell using FPDF to download PDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using FPDF library to convert or download MYSQL data from a database into a PDF form. However, I'm experiencing a challenge when a string in a cell is too large it overlaps to the next down cell and all data is disorganized. How do I counter this to have an elastic cell that is able to accommodate all the cell contents? The cell with issues is column SMS TEXT fetched as `$column_sms_text` ...Anyone?

```
//Create a new PDF file
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

//Fields Name position
$Y_Fields_Name_position = 20;
//Table position, under Fields Name
$Y_Table_Position = 26;

//First create each Field Name
//Gray color filling each Field Name box
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
//Bold Font for Field Name
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(5);
$pdf->Cell(10,6,'ID',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(15);
$pdf->Cell(100,6,'SMS TEXT',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(115);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'RECIVER NUMBER',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(145);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'TIME SENT',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(175);
$pdf->Cell(45,6,'DELIVERLY STATUS',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(220);
$pdf->Ln();

//Now show the columns
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(5);
$pdf->MultiCell(10,6,$column_id,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(15);
$pdf->MultiCell(100,6,$column_sms_text,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(115);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,$column_receiver_number,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(145);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,$column_time_sent,1,'L');
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(175);
$pdf->MultiCell(45,6,$column_status,1,'L');

$pdf->SetX(220);

//Create lines (boxes) for each ROW (Product)

$i = 0;
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
while ($i < $number_of_products)
{
    $pdf->SetX(5);
    $pdf->MultiCell(215,6,'',1);
    $i = $i +1;
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $i = 0;
 $pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
 while ($i < $number_of_products)
 {
    $pdf->SetX(5);
    $pdf->MultiCell(215,6,'',1);
    $i = $i +1;
 }
 $content = $pdf->Output("pdf_1.pdf",'F'); // download PDF
 $pdf->Output(); // open PDF
```

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: where exactly should this line come in?

Comment: Tried that an apparently there was no display or download.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.